# PDO prepared statement Error 1064

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, mysql-error-1064, insert-into

I getting this error trying to insert data into my table.

Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username`,`password`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`emailcode``) VALUES ('' at line 1 )

My code looks like this .. 
$reg_data is an array that contains the data from $_POST.

```
        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `',array_keys($reg_data)) . '`';
        $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $reg_data) . '\'';


        $prep = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (`'.$fields.'`) VALUES (?)');

        $prep->bindParam(1, $data);

        $prep->execute();

        print_r($prep->errorInfo());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see the error it clearly shows you the use of double back-tics emailcode``

Once you have added backtiks in the implode you are adding again in insert query 
(`'.$fields.'`)

change

```
 $fields = '`' . implode('`, `',array_keys($reg_data)) . '`';
```

to

```
 $fields =  implode('`, `',array_keys($reg_data)) ;
```

Or just use it without bacticks as you have already added using implode

```
$prep = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` ('.$fields.') VALUES (?)');
```